# How to reference definition variables nested in a class from main

Tags: python, class, reference

I would like to know how (in Python) to reference a variable that is inside a def, inside a class. For example:

```
class class_name():
    .
    .    # Some more definitions in here
    . 

    def definition_name():
        variable_of_interest = 10    # 10 chosen arbitrarily
    .
    .    # Some more definitions in here
    .

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    # Here I want to reference variable_of_interest. Example:
    if variable_of_interest = 10
        do stuff
```

Even better, how can I reference the variable in main if the example looks like:

```
class class_name():

    def __init__(self):
        # Some code
        def _another_definition():
            variable_of_interest = 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #same as before
```

So basically how do I reference a variable that is placed like Class()>Def()>Def()>Variable in main?

Comment: can it be returned in the function? or be a class variable?

Comment: It is a good thing that variables have limited scope. If you want to make it accessible, create an additional property for it, like `self.variable_of_interest`.

Comment: @depperm I'm not sure I understand what you're asking but the variable of interest would be defined inside a definition that is inside another definition, inside a class. If I put the variable of interest inside the class directly, then I know I can just do `class_name.variable_of_interest` to get the value. But I have not figured out how to do this when the variable is nested deeper in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're calling a `def` is actually either a function or in this case a method in a class.

Variables defined in a method are normally not available. That's the whole idea of *encapsulation*.

If you want to access variables in a class they should either class or instance variables.

A variable defined in an instance, a *member*, would need to be accessed as part of an instance of the class. It's defined in `__init__()`.

For example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
```

Accessed as:

```
x = MyClass() # instantiate an object of this class
x.data # access instance member
```

A class variable can be defined at the top of the class definition:

```
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    i = 12345
```

Then it would be accessed with `MyClass.i`.

Look at this [Python tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) to understand this better.

If you really want to have a variable in a class method also be accessible directly in the main context then you can make it a global variable by preceding it with `global`. Otherwise variables are by default local and only accessible in the same scope.

Comment: So I cannot access the variable unless it's a class variable or a member? How would I access the member?

Comment: I updated the answer. Look at the tutorial link to get these basics down

Comment: @DamianConnors Do you get it now? Mark as answered if it helped

Comment: What if the class has arguments? I'm trying what you wrote here but getting an error. Mine looks like this: `class autocollect(gr.top_block, Qt.Qwidget):`

Comment: There are no "arguments" for a class. You're mixing up the definition of the class with the creation of an instance. The answer I gave answered your original question